# How to mic a fursuit performer?

Tags: microphone, live-sound

I'd like to mic up a singer for a live performance, which sounds normal, but there's a twist: the singer will be wearing a fursuit to perform: something like a mascot costume, including a giant foam head that completely covers the performer's head. It makes exterior mics somewhat impractical, so I'm thinking either some way of secreting a lav in the muzzle or snout, or something in a headset form factor (which I hope would conveniently come with monitor earpieces as well) which can be worn normally inside the head.

Although it's for a live setting only, so I'm not expecting studio-quality sound, I've heard some set-ups cause problems like making the performer's breathing very loud, and I would like to avoid problems like that. On the flip side, bleed from other performers or instruments will be less of a worry!

I'd like either general tips on what qualities to look for in a mic for this purpose and how to site it to avoid problems like breath noise; or ideally, more specific advice on what works and doesn't work, from someone who has done this before.